# Apply formatting to selected page numbers of index

Tags: formatting, color, indexing, imakeidx

I would like to apply a formatting to *some* of the page numbers in an index.  In the MWE below, when I use `\index{}` the page number should be in black and when I use `\MyIndex{}` the page number should be formatted with `\FormatPageNumber{}`:

The MWE below produces the results on the left. What changes do I need to make to the `\MyIndex{}` macro to achieve the results on the right:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand*{\FormatPageNumber}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\bfseries#1}}
\newcommand*{\MyIndex}[1]{%
    \begingroup
        % Want to apply \FormatPageNumber{} to this page number ONLY in the index.
        \index{#1}%
    \endgroup
}%

\begin{document}

stuff\index{test}
\clearpage
more stuff\MyIndex{test}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting commands for the page number can be added using the syntax `term|formatting`, see page 5 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/indexing/makeindex/doc/makeindex.pdf).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}\pagecolor{white}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\newcommand*{\FormatPageNumber}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\bfseries#1}}
\newcommand*{\MyIndex}[1]{%
    \begingroup
        \index{#1|FormatPageNumber}%
    \endgroup
}%

\begin{document}
stuff\index{test}
\clearpage
more stuff\MyIndex{test}

\printindex

\end{document}
```